# How to reference multi-word dictionary key in mako?

Tags: python, mako

I am passing a csv file to Mako via `csv.DictReader`, and the dictionary uses row headers for keys. Some of these have names like 'Entry Id'. Mako throws out errors when I try to reference these multi-word keys in a template. Specifically, the error message is `mako.exceptions.SyntaxException: (SyntaxError) invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)`.

The following code demonstrates the issue I am experiencing:

```
from mako.template import Template

mydata = {'foo': 'bar', 'better foo': 'beach bar'}
working_template = Template("Let's go to the ${foo}")
fail_template = Template("Let's go to the ${better foo}")

# this works
print working_template.render(**mydata)
# this generates an Exception
print fail_template.render(**mydata)
```

Is there a way to escape spaces for multi-word keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one way that works, but I'd rather send the dictionary as **kwargs if possible. Here is the working solution:

```
from mako.template import Template

mydata = {'foo': 'bar', 'better foo': 'beach bar'}
working_template = Template("Let's go to the ${foo}")
fail_template = Template("Let's go to the ${mydata['better foo']}")

print working_template.render(**mydata)
print fail_template.render(mydata=mydata)
```