# Mako template implicitly refer to calling script's variables

Tags: python, mako

I've got a bunch of variables in the script that renders a Mako template. But what I find increasingly is that I just pass it all through directly, which makes for a bunch of churn.

Is there any way that I can set up Mako so that a reference inside a Mako template can implicitly resolve to a *global* variable/function in the rendering script?

Comment: how many view's / routes do you have?? i have a route for each page where I return some stuff and inherit each page from a master page that calls each component

Comment: well generally when you are working with python as a backend you have a section called views that you have each view, pages templates stuff like that. route would be the route to each view where you do some python and then render a page... each time you render for each page/route you send different data thats relevant for the page you are on.

Comment: Not in this case. I'm just invoking mako on a bunch of templates. There is no frontend or backend, it's just rendering the templates.

Comment: ok well can you provide an example of what it would look like? i have an idea of a way to do it

Comment: oh another thing you could try... you can make python blocks in the template where you call a function and pass a variable... that function could be another template file if set up correctly

Comment: @JohnRuddell: It's just like `files = [ 'filepath1', 'filepath2' ] for file in files: Template(filename=file).render()`, but with a whole bunch of data like `files` itself passed in.

Comment: and you want to pass pieces of file to different templates?

Comment: No, I pass all the files (the list) to all the templates. And I also pass basically everything else. Hence the question.

Comment: no i got that... I mean the desired result... you WANT to pass specific files to specific templates right?

Comment: @JohnRuddell: Nope. I'm pretty happy with the result I have now. I just want it to be automatic instead of explicitly listing every single global variable and function.

Comment: ok well if you put all of the global variables into a dictionary and pass just that one dict you could bypass calling all of them... so like if you have `temp = {globalvar1: 'stuff', globalvar2: 'stuff'}` then just send temp1 like this... `temp1 = {mydict: temp}` that way its wrapped inside a dict so if you called temp in the mako part it would be the whole dict.. if im understanding your problem that could probably help :)

Comment: it doesn't really help that much, since I'd have to explicitly initialize the dict with every variable, which isn't really easier than passing every variable to `render()`.

Comment: OHHHH why not just do this?? `temp = {globalvar1: 'stuff', globalvar2: 'stuff'}` and then render the whole dict in one call? `Template.render(temp)` one sec i'm going to look at exactly how I do it to be sure

Comment: are you using the pyramid framework?

Comment: @JohnRuddell: Nope, just bog-standard Python 3 and Mako. If I made a dict beforehand, how would initializing the dict be any different to passing the stuff in to the render function?

Comment: using the dict can allow you to send multiple things through with one render call.. I use pyramid framework which allows you to send a dictionary object through one render call.. that object can contain as much data as you want.. and then you just call out each specific thing you want to use. you could try this though.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381391/how-to-reference-multi-word-dictionary-key-in-mako